# Gigabyte GA-H61M-S1 motherboard infinite boot

Tags: boot, motherboard, cmos

I have 3 computers with the Gigabyte GA-H61M-S1 rev 2.1 motherboard.
I was using one of them but after restarting it, it got into an infinite boot with no display (integrated GPU there is no internal GPU) and no USB input and there is no POST test, no Gigabyte logo, and no DEL/F9/F12 to enter BIOS. I say an "infinite loop", not a "boot loop".

At first, I did think that it was only with this computer, but after testing the 2 others they have the same problem.
Here is what I tried (multiple times):

- unplug the PSU from the wall plug and pressing the power button for 1 minute + removing the motherboard battery.
- using a jumper to clear the CMOS.

It doesn't stop there. Even without understanding how this following miracle happened, one in 10 trials after resetting the BIOS and after 10-15 minutes of black screen, the screen finally displayed something which is the 3 option button:

- load optimized and boot
- load optimized default and reboot
- enter BIOS
  Whatever I choose after restarting the computer the nightmare comes back.

What should I do? Flash the BIOS, maybe?

Comment: The bad news is you may have to replace it. Unfortunately what you describe is very familiar to anyone that used that brand.

Comment: @ChanganAuto My bad i'am just a computer technicien doing internship in a third world country it would take ages to ask the administration for spare parts

Comment: Are all 3 on the same PSU ? Are you sure the PSU is working ?

Comment: @harrymc No they are not on the same psu every motherboard have a complet kit of equipment (RAM + CPU + HDD + PSU) and a case and yes the cpu is working the cpu fan do rotate

Comment: It seems strange that 3 computers died simultaneously. Or were they already dead when you arrived?

Comment: @harrymc one died when i restarted it the two others were already

Comment: It seems that you were given 3 carcasses, in the hope that you could revive them.

Comment: @harrymc And do you think that it is "doable", are there any hope? :/ ?

Comment: I'm far away, remember. Try perhaps to analyze better the symptoms, perhaps to swap parts between them trying to get one at least working. Inspect visually the motherboards, test the PSU voltage, try some components in computers known to work to find which are working. Those are all my ideas.

Comment: I just had exactly that about a month ago. The computer only returned when I booted with 2 out of 4 DDR4 sticks. An entire channel of memory was dead. ( BTW remember: a first boot after memory change might take upto one minute! ). After a week, I still couldn't boot with the extra slots. About a week later, they worked normally like nothing ever happened. I still don't know what had happened.

Comment: @Netan so two stick which didn't work one week ago now works like nothing happened?

Comment: @Capacity213 exactly like you said. YES. I am a cybersecurity researcher and sysadmin several years now, and a computers-enthusiast for over a decade. I built countless systems for friends and troubleshooted Linux and Windows OSs running on many, many hardwares. And I was clueless. I figured it was the age of the CPU ( I7-6700, which was running ever since I purchased it ) or some blown capacitor but then it started working again (!) haha

Comment: @Capacity213 correction: not sticks, the DDR SLOTS. A whole memory channel was dead ( so, both red slots didn't work, while two black slots worked, on H170 GAMING 3 )

Comment: Try to disconnect the computer from power, push the power button several times and leave it disconnected for the night. It might help deplete charge from the capacitors on the motherboard and the PSU ( as far as my limited knowledge of electronics goes )

Comment: @Netan This is what i did today before leaving work i did unplug from the powerwall and also removed the cmos battery and wait till today in the hope of working tomorrow thanks for the tip

Comment: @Netan by the way i did have a call with someone who work in a computer hardware store and told me to remove the sticks and try one by one

Comment: @Capacity213 haha exactly what I did, which led me to my conclution. It wasn't a problem with the sticks as much as it was the MOBO's fault.